# Finding JTAG/UART Connections

Tags: firmware, hardware, serial-communication, jtag

I need help identifying the UART or JTAG connections on this board.

I would like to dump the firmware using a pirate bus.

[image: Front-side]

[image: Back-side]

Comment: The first thing I'd start from is searching for datasheet. Did you check the large white plastic header with 4 pins for being serial port ?

Comment: I was advised to look into the 25L6436F chip and use flashrom, I will be using a soic clip 8 w/ a raspberry pi. now I just have to wait for that to arrive from china. however I need to find a tutorial that properly explains how to determine if pins/pads are actual serial connectors, either using a multimeter or logic analyzer.

Answer (score 2):

In the second picture on the bottom there is an nonpupulated connector, whose pins are labeled RX and TX. Thats at least one of maybe more uart interfaces.

You should additionaly check the traces on the pcb between that connector and the main micro controller. It might be that the nonpopulated pads at R1 need to be shortened to have a connection.